# Auto initializing PK in Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity, primary-key

I am using Entity framework and would like to have a constructor in each of my entities that initializes the PK property to `Guid.NewGuid()`. I was wondering if there was a way to have this done automatically instead of having to do it myself, maybe playing with the .TT file scripts that create my C# source code. Any ideas?

Comment: Put default value as NewID() in SQL Server and set the column as StoreGeneratedPattern in your model. A new guid will be created as you Save your object context.

Answer (score 0):

T4 templates are so not object oriented...

Maybe you can do that in the constructor of a base class...